# Probability of breaking a plate and a saucer

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> There were 6 plates, 5 saucers, and 5 cups on the counter and while one of the kitchen staff was washing it, he accidentally dropped and broke two dish wares.  What is the probability that he broke a plate and a saucer?

I thought that he broke two dish wares at the same time so I could use combination here to find the number of outcomes.

6C1 x 5C1 = 30

This is the number of ways where a plate and saucer were dropped.

16C2 = 120

For the total number of ways to drop 2 dish wares.

This gives me a probability of:

30/120 = 1/4

The answer key showed that it is supposed to be:

6/16 x 5/15 = 1/8 or 12.5%

I am confused since this can only happen if you drop them separately. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Just to confirm, does 'dishware' include cups? I'm assuming it does. In that case, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct, and the book answer is wrong, but it would be good to understand that the question can be tackled in two ways, both of which give the same answer

---

The question has not specifiied the order in which the dishware is broken.

However whether you break them one by one, or together, the **probability** will remain the same. But you have to be careful to match the numerator and denominator.

For breaking plate, then saucer OR saucer, then plate,

Pr $= \dfrac6{16}\dfrac5{15} + \dfrac5{16}\dfrac6{15} = \dfrac14$

While breaking them together, we get
$\dfrac{\dbinom61 \dbinom51} {\dbinom{16}2} = \dfrac14$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The answer key assumes the plate would be dropped before the cup, and so is off by a factor of 2; the correct answer using its logic would be $6/16*5/15 \text{ (plate then cup)} + 5/16 * 6/15 \text{ (cup then plate)} = 1/4$.